# Is there a way to disable the crown button while in an app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing an app for weightlifting that includes a Wear OS app. I'm testing the app on my own device and I've found that while wearing wrist straps, I tend to hit the crown (middle) button on my watch (Fossil Sport) accidentally, sending me back to the watchface. I know I can handle the other two hardware buttons, but can't seem to find a way to handle the middle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is *no*. When in an app on Wear OS, the device's main hardware button functions the same as the Home button on an Android phone, and you can't override the Home button.

Longer answer: devs have found various hacks to do this on Android more generally, which you can find by searching here on SO with terms like "disable Android home button". I just looked through a few and didn't find any which would work on current versions of Wear OS, but you might.

Also, you'll find some good discussion of why you seriously **shouldn't** do this - most of which **does** also apply on Wear OS. I refer you back to the short answer above.